# How to display a QColor from QColorDialog in a widget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qcolor, qcolordialog

I have a ColorPicker dialog like:

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::black, this, "Pick a color",  QColorDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```

The result of that I put in a QLineEdit via `color.name()` , e.g. #ff0000 .
I would like to display that color as the red field in this example, too

[image]

I don't know what Widget to pick for this to display? QPicture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enhanced this answer [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-5944.html). If you already grabbed the QColor in `color`, you can try for a `QLabel* label`:

```
QPalette palette = label->palette();
palette.setColor(label->backgroundRole(), color);    
label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
label->setPalette(palette);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, if you have QColor in color and QLabel *label -

```
label->setStyleSheet("background-color:"+color.name()+";");
```